# In coq, how do you declare/prove enumeration elements are distinct?

Tags: coq

I'm having fun introducing myself to Coq. Right now I'm stuck doing proofs about an enumeration:

```
Inductive Comparison : Type :=
  | EQUAL
  | GREATER
  | LESSER.
```

Is it implicitly true that EQUAL and GREATER and LESSER are different (this seems to be what the docs imply), or is that undetermined with just the above code? I can't figure out how to prove it.

```
Proposition comp_sanity: forall x : Comparison,
  x = EQUAL /\ x = GREATER -> False.
Proof.
intros x H_eqgr.
```

gives me:

```
H_eqgr : x = EQUAL /\ x = GREATER
--------------------------------------------------
False
```

but then I'm stuck:

```
Coq> contradiction H_eqgr.
Error: Not a contradiction.
```

What should I be doing here to have a fully (distinctly) enumerated type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case I would go for the `discriminate` tactics instead of `contradiction`. A short version would be:

```
Proposition comp_sanity: forall x : Comparison,
  x = EQUAL /\ x = GREATER -> False.
Proof.
now intros x [h1 h2]; subst; discriminate.
Qed.
```

which translate to

```
Proposition comp_sanity: forall x : Comparison,
  x = EQUAL /\ x = GREATER -> False.
Proof.
intros x hx.
destruct hx as [h1 h2].
rewrite h1 in h2.
now discriminate h2.
Qed.
```

without the `intros` pattern magic.

Best,
V.

Answer (score 4):

The `contradiction` tactic does not do much more work than try to find something in your context that has type `False`. Unfortunately, while your context has a contradiction, it is not yet clear to `contradiction`.

The `congruence` tactic performs more work, and understands that, indeed, two different constructors are not equal (we say that constructors are disjoint).

In this context, this is more or less the same as calling `subst` to propagate the equalities about `x`, which results in one hypothesis `EQUAL = GREATER`, and then calling `discriminate`, a tactic which finds absurdity in equality of different constructors.

Comment: Okay, subst and congruence didn't help me, but I did get discriminate to work. Is there a better way to write this?

    Proof.
    intros x H_eqgr.
    assert (x = EQUAL) as H_eq.
      apply H_eqgr.
    assert (x = GREATER) as H_gr.
      apply H_eqgr.
    rewrite H_eq in H_gr.
    discriminate H_gr.

Comment: @AnthonyTowns intros. inversion H. subst. contradict H1. discriminate.

Comment: @AnthonyTowns A tad shorter proof: `intros ? [contra ->]. discriminate.` utilizing a bit of `intros` magic.